# What are the rewards for different ranks by knock-out?

Tags: splatoon

I noticed that knock-out in different ranks in ranked mode of Splatoon yielded different rewards (in exp and gold). For example, winning by knock-out while having rank C gave be 1600 points, while in rank C+ this yielded me 2000 points. What are the different rewards for different ranks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I compiled my own list with some personal experience and by watching some footage of Ranked Battles on YouTube. For convenience I included the reward for winning without KO. One thing to note is that a *KO Bonus* is the same amount of points as a *Win Bonus* for the next rank in line.

**Regular Battle**

The Win Bonus for a regular match is always 300 points. Regardless of level or rank.

**Ranked Battle**

- **Rank C-**

  - Win Bonus: 1000
  - KO Bonus: 1300
- **Rank C**

  - Win Bonus: 1300
  - KO Bonus: 1600
- **Rank C+**

  - Win Bonus: 1600
  - KO Bonus: 2000

---

- **Rank B-**

  - Win Bonus: 2000
  - KO Bonus: 2300
- **Rank B**

  - Win Bonus: 2300
  - KO Bonus: 2600
- **Rank B+**

  - Win Bonus: 2600
  - KO Bonus: 3000

---

- **Rank A-**

  - Win Bonus: 3000
  - KO Bonus: 3300
- **Rank A**

  - Win Bonus: 3300
  - KO Bonus: 3600
- **Rank A+**

  - Win Bonus: 3600
  - KO Bonus: 4000

---

- **Rank S**

  - Win Bonus: 4000
  - KO Bonus: 5000
- **Rank S+**

  - Win Bonus: 5000
  - KO Bonus: 6000

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to extrapolate based on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/222795/56730) because I'm not even a B-rank yet.

C-: 1300

C: 1600

C+: 2000

B-: 2300

B: 2600

B+: 3000

A-: 3300

A: 3600

A+: 4000

As you can see, there's a clear pattern here.